# Mongoerror: failed to connect to server localhost:27017 on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have created an application using MEAN, After that, I have created the ec2 Linux instance, where I am running this application.I have installed all the dependencies.

Added port 27017 on security group page.
running the command on the ec2 instance as `node server.js`

Node: My mongo DB is outside my cloud instance i.e on my laptop.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: make sure you have install `mongodb` and start  `mongodb server`

Comment: where to start? Do I have to start the mongo shell on my laptop? I have installed the mongodb also.

Comment: just exec command `mongod`, and use command `mongo` to check if you have start the server successfully.

Comment: it is already running outside the cloud.

Comment: you mean your server is on ec2, but your db is on your local laptop? I think it's impossible your ec2 server visit your local db. Because your local laptop don't have public IP, so ec2 server cannot find your machine in the internet. Maybe you can try to use `mlab`

Comment: ok..that means I have to switch my db to `mlab`

Comment: if you are using this for development you can install mongodb on ec2 only and and have access to database on the same server that will even reduce your latency and is good for production as well if you don't have a large  set of database and not using sharding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your laptop to internet which is almost impossible (and you shouldn't). That means you need a **MongoDB server** which is accessible by your EC2 Linux instance.

You may use a free mongodb hosting such as [mlab](http://www.mlab.com)

On the other hand you can enable another EC2 instance and setup your own mongodb. Beware that you may need to setup firewall if it's not an internal network.